# Bootstrap on Rails working wrong or no. Short navbar on full screen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I wanna see a full navbar menu on my page, but something wrong and i sad. Plus, the icons (Home, Contacts) drop down under the menu - icon. Not at a line. Maybe its a addaptive problem, but i using my laptop, not a phone or smt. I dont know what the problem, that why i put full adding part with bootstrap. Over 2 days i cant find an answer. Im sure what that will be actually a simply answer, but im new on this stuff.

This is my application.html.erb code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

```
<%= yield %>
```

```
This is what a add on my Gemfile: 
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.beta'

This is my application.scss: 
@import "bootstrap";

This is my application.js: 
// = require rails-ujs
// = require turbolinks
// = require_tree .

= require jquery3
= require popper
= require bootstrap-sprockets (I dont know should i use a comment or not, but last 3 strings from githab/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem without comment)

And that what i have: [enter image description here][1]

I wanna see a full version of navbar, but something wrong i think. Help to young developer, please!
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong classes. You're using bootstrap 4 alpha class, but need to use bootstrap 4 beta class. This would be an example of a navbar in bootstrap 4 beta:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Say, what is your name? i'll give that name to my first child! Thanks!!